# unexpected namespace prefix xmlns found for tag gridview

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridlayout

What could be the problem here? I have tried removing the xmlns but it is still giving me an error.

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221;
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
android:orientation=”vertical”
android:background=”@color/white”
>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </div>

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have that </div>?

Comment: Do you really have fancy quotes in your code? Please make sure your sample is exactly matching code that has the issue.

Comment: However xmlns is mandatory. And it should be: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

> xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221;

Just remove the line and paste this:

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

It should do the trick, seems like you copied from a place where it was formatted!

Do not forget to remove the div tag (doesn't exist in android):

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<!--remove div -->
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

`"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

**NOT** 
`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221;`

And delete <`/div>`

```
   <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
        android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
        android:orientation=”vertical”
        android:background=”@color/white”
    >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```